# My car low mileage

Tags: car

Recently my car went in to water,and after that it was not getting start,but after lot of try by myself the car got start,and after that day I visited to the car company workshop,they checked the car and told me that water has not damaged my car in any manner,but after few days I noticed that my car mileage has dropped a lot,and it is taking a very long self to start the car.then again I visited the car workshop they done the general check up and told me they are not finding any problem anywhere.and self has also has started working properly,so please let me know is there any possibility of my car has got damaged 
My car is grand i10 2018 model

Comment: Why did your car go into water? Did it drive itself or did you?

Comment: My car went in to flood during rain last month